# Redirect Loop with CiviContribute

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page, redirect

I have a similar problem to [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6634/wordpress-redirect-loop-with-civicontribute) and [this](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34697.0) issues, a redirect loop occurs on coming back from the payment system after making a contribution.

The difference with the 2 previous links is that the problem :

- does not occur every time for logged out users
- does not occur for logged in users
- occurs only on a "second" contribution page. The main contribution page works fine.

When it's not working, the return URL is like this : /?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&

instead of having the other get attributes like the contribution ID and such.

This site is using WP Rocket as caching plugin. I added exceptions for the contribution pages' URLs to avoid caching problems, but the problem persists and I do not know how to debug this issue... Especially that it seems to be randomly happening...

The payment system is Ogone.
CiviCRM version : 4.6
WP version 4.8

Any suggestion appreciated!